# compare string elements and check if the last character is different

Tags: python, string

How to format the last character of the elements of

```
> Apple0 = 2,  Apple1 = 3, Apple2 = 8, Mango = 10, Banana = 15, Grape0 = 11,
> Grape1 = 20 Potato = 5
```

to

```
Apple[0] = 2,  Apple[1] = 3, Apple[2] = 8, Mango = 10, Banana = 15, Grape[0] = 11, Grape[1] = 20, Potato = 5
```

I found some examples online using `pandas` but unfortunately i am not being able to install `panda` plugin to my pycharm

Comment: What does `type(list)` give you?

Comment: it is giving me exactly  

Apple0 = 2,  Apple1 = 3, Apple2 = 8, Mango = 10, Banana = 15, Grape0 = 11,
Grape1 = 20 Potato = 5

Comment: no thats the actual `list` print it's `type`, also don't name your `list` using the `built-in list`

Comment: yes, I want to combine the similar types into array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

loaded_items = {
    'Apple0': 2,
    'Apple1': 3,
    'Apple2': 8,
    'Mango':10,
    'Banana': 15,
    'Grape0': 11,
    'Grape1': 20,
    'Potato': 5
}
items = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in loaded_items.items():
    key_letter = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, k))
    items[key_letter][len(items[key_letter]) + 1] = v
print(items)
```

Comment: getting something like

{'Apple': {1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3}, 'Mango': {1: 3}, 'Banana': {1: 3}, 'Grape': {1: 3, 2: 3}, 'Potato': {1: 3}})

Comment: I'll need you to explain better then.

Comment: the above case is just a representation, you can access the items as an array like this: `print(items['Apple'][2])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
import pprint


loaded_items = {
    'Apple0': 2,
    'Apple1': 3,
    'Apple2': 8,
    'Mango':10,
    'Banana': 15,
    'Grape0': 11,
    'Grape1': 20,
    'Potato': 5
}
d = {}
for key, val in loaded_items.items():
    match = re.search(r'\d+$', key)
    if match:
        endchar = match.group()
        key = key.rstrip(endchar)
        d.setdefault(key, [])
        d[key].append(val)
    else:
        d[key] = val

pprint.pprint(d)
```

### Output

```
{'Apple': [8, 2, 3], 'Banana': 15, 'Grape': [11, 20], 'Mango': 10, 'Potato': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a file of the form

```
Apple0 = 2,  Apple1 = 3, Apple2 = 8, Mango = 10, Banana = 15, Grape0 = 11,
Grape1 = 20 Potato = 5
```

And you want to reformat it to

```
Apple[0] = 2,  Apple[1] = 3, Apple[2] = 8, Mango = 10, Banana = 15, Grape[0] = 11,
Grape[1] = 20 Potato = 5
```

Easy:

```
import re

token_regex = r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)'
replacement_regex = r'\1[\2]'

updated_string = re.sub(
    token_regex, 
    replacement_regex, 
    file.read()
 )

 print updated_string
```

Output:

```
 Apple[0] = 2,  Apple[1] = 3, Apple[2] = 8, Mango = 10, Banana = 15, Grape[0] = 11,
 Grape[1] = 20 Potato = 5
```